# Redux Provider not working in React

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

so i've come across a strange issue where the Provider component wont work when i try and host my website. If i want to run it locally using yarn start it works fine with the Provider. I'm pretty sure my hosting setup is correct as if i replace the Provider with a jsx component it displays that jsx page. Heres what i have at the moment in my App.js file.

```
export default class App extends Component {
 render() {

 return (
   <Provider store={store}>
     <AppContainer />
   </Provider>
 );
}
}
```

Any help is much appreciated, thanks.

here is my package.json

```
{
   "name": "ca-website",
   "version": "0.1.0",
   "private": true,
   "homepage": "/build",
   "dependencies": {
      "axios": "^0.17.1",
      "material-ui": "^0.20.0",
      "raven-js": "^3.20.1",
      "react": "^16.2.0",
      "react-bootstrap": "^0.31.5",
      "react-collapsible": "^2.0.3",
      "react-device-detect": "^0.1.0",
      "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
      "react-ga": "^2.4.1",
      "react-google-maps": "^9.4.3",
      "react-icons": "^2.2.7",
      "react-localization": "^0.1.6",
      "react-lottie": "^1.0.0",
      "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
      "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
      "react-scripts": "1.0.17",
      "react-sidebar": "^2.3.2",
      "react-tap-event-plugin": "^3.0.2",
      "react-typist": "^2.0.4",
      "redux": "^3.7.2",
      "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
      "redux-loop": "git+ssh://git@stash.cabforce.com:7999/cod/redux-
       loop#cod",
      "redux-promise": "^0.5.3",
      "redux-storage": "^4.1.2",
      "redux-storage-decorator-filter": "^1.1.8",
      "redux-storage-decorator-migrate": "^1.1.0",
      "redux-storage-engine-localstorage": "^1.1.4",
      "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
      "sweetalert": "^2.1.0"
     },
     "scripts": {
       "start": "react-scripts start",
       "build": "react-scripts build",
       "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
       "eject": "react-scripts eject"
      }
    }
```

Comment: I'm guessing when you run it locally you are running a development / local version. If you run your build script and then try run your app with `node dist/index.js` (or whatever your path to your built entry point is) does it run fine on your local?

Comment: sorry i'm not familiar with node dist command, could you explain it further, but i tested the build folder using serve -s build and it worked fine. I'm a bit confused as to why it will work locally and not when i host it cause I know my hosting is set up correctly as i can replace the provider with a jsx component and it will work

Comment: the node command is just telling node to run your application from your build folder. `dist/index.js` is just an example. Your project might be set up different. Maybe you can update your post with your `package.json` file and I can give more details.

Comment: ah ok, i ran it from the build folder there works perfectly.

Comment: i posted the important stuff from the package.json there

Comment: Any reason you have your provider in the app.js? I haven't seen it done this way (not saying it is necessarily wrong) but I am just wondering if that may be causing issues. I typically have my provider wrapping my app component with in the index.js file. Would have thought it would be much the same but may be worth trying...

Comment: yeah thats a good suggestion, i'll give it a try

Comment: unfortunately putting the provider component in the index.js class didnt work either, thanks for the help though

Comment: If this is a `create-react-app` then the `homepage` affects where the build SAP can be deployed. I think your problem is that you host the website on some `myurl.com` but it should be `myurl.com\build`. Read in `README.md` about `homepage` and build for relative path.

Comment: thats actually how i'm doing it "homepage": "https://myUrl.com/build/" i just didnt want to post the url i was using so i changed it to "homepage" : /build above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to fix this, All the stuff above is correct, turns out it was a ReactRouter issue, i was wrapping my components in BrowserHistory, changed it to HashRouter and voila it worked. this thread helped me a lot [React-router urls don't work when refreshing or writting manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writting-manually)